# Creating and applying a lambda in a single line in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I hope this isn't a silly question, but is there any way of achieving the following sort of thing in C#?

```
int y = (x => x * x)(9);
```

I know I can do this:

```
delegate int Transformer(int x);
Transformer square = x => x * x;
int y = square(9);
```

But is there any way to do the same thing more concisely? If not, is there a good reason why not?

Comment: How about `int y = 9 * 9;`? Would you mind showing an example where this would make sense? I can't think of one.

Comment: @delnan What if you want to pass, say, `a+b` into the lambda?

Comment: @David: Even if then, and even assuming the expression is too long to repeat or has side effects, an intermediate variable (e.g. `int ab = a+b; int y = ab * ab;`) is simpler, more regular and perhaps shorter.

Comment: @delnan Actually I do agree with your latest comment. I was just trying to come up with a possible  justification. Lambdas are surely only beneficial when you need a delegate.

Comment: @delnan: For that matter, I think `int y = 81;` probably captures the intent nicely :) But the answers below are more what I was hoping for! I don't have a particular usage example in mind here actually -- I was just curious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
int y = ((Func<int,int>)(x => x * x))(9);
```

or use it an a delegate creation expression:

```
int y = new Func<int,int>(x => x * x)(9);
```

It's not terribly useful though...

(I've used `Func<int, int>` as an alternative to your `Transformer` delegate, to use the built-in delegate types where possible.)

Comment: Thanks Jon. Just as a note for anyone else who reads this: `Func` is apparently in the `System.Core` assembly (I didn't know, and had to go away and look it up).

Comment: @Stuart: It is in .NET 3.5; in .NET 4 it's in mscorlib.

Comment: Ah ok. I was testing this under Mono, which probably explains it.

Answer (score 5):

Because a lambda is not associated with a delegate type, you need to specify the delegate type when you define a lambda, either on the left hand side or on the right hand side.

This should do the trick:

```
int result = new Transformer(x => x * x)(9);
```

The same thing more concisely:

```
int x = 9;
int result = x * x;
```

Comment: Thanks dtb. I gave the answer to Jon because using `Func` is perhaps slightly better, but much appreciated.